# How to configure package Revise to use Project.toml in project folders instead of user/host, Project.toml?

Tags: julia, package-management

Objective: to configure package, Revise to use Project.toml in project folders.

Procedure followed:
a) downloaded and installed the dependency packages of Revise
b) downloaded Revise.jl-master.zip, unzipped to `/opt/julia/julia-1.1.0/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/Revise.jl-master`, renamed folder to Revise.
c)invoked `julia> using Revise`

Error:

```
InitError: SystemError: opening file "/opt/julia/julia-1.1.0/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/Project.toml" No such file or directory
```

Observation:

```
/opt/julia/julia-1.1.0/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/<PACKAGE_NAME>/Project.toml files are available
```

Please guide me in configuring package Revise to use Project.toml in project folders instead of user/host Project.toml

Comment: did you fix the typo `Projct.toml`?

Comment: typo error happened only in the question, now updated!

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the [package manager](https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1/) to install packages? You would probably have a lot fewer difficulties if you used the package manager.

Comment: testing offline package installation!